# Shifting from python to pypy

Tags: python, cmake, pypy

I am currently working on a project where the source files are all written in python. The files/modules are currently being run on a python interpreter(CPython). I want to use PyPy interpreter instead as i see it is much more efficient. Is there way how I can change the interpreter from the CMakeLists.txt file so the build process takes in PyPy interpreter instead of the python default interpreter? 
I have a project named P and it contains a CMakeLists.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

When it needs python interpreter, `CMakeLists.txt` usually uses [find_package(PythonInterp)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonInterp.html), which searches python executable and sets `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE` to the path where it is located.

You may set this *cache* variable when call `cmake`:

```
cmake -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=<path-to-PyPy> ...
```

so it will not search executable but use one you provide.